# Bootflat accordions with button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this block

```
<div class="panel-group panel-group-lists collapse in" id="accordion2">            
        <div class="panel panel-margin">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour" class="collapsed">
                        <span class="badge badge-danger badge-reports badge-reports-text">NEW</span>
                        <span class="report-title">VIN Code 1M8GDM9A_KPO42788</span>
                        <span class="report-date">11 jun / 12:54 AM</span>
                        <!-- dropdown must be here -->
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0;">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I need to add dropdown button in right part of panel with glyphicon-option-horizontal icon. How to put button to this accordion? I tried all that I find in bootflat and bootstrap: input-group-btn etc. Help me please to solve this issue/

Comment: Where do you want to put the drop down exactly. Which div ?

Comment: I need dropdown in `a` tag

Answer (score 0):

Added a `span` like this.

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour" class="collapsed">
   <span class="badge badge-danger badge-reports badge-reports-text">NEW</span>
   <span class="report-title">VIN Code 1M8GDM9A_KPO42788</span>
   <span class="report-date">11 jun / 12:54 AM</span>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></span>
</a>
```

Hope this will help.